# Formatar string qt html charset

Tags: string, qt, codificação-de-caracteres

Tenho a seguinte string:
QString str = "Macarr & # x e 3 ; o integral.\nMacarrão integral.< br/>"
(coloquei espaço entre todos caracteres do caracter especial se não não ficaria visivel e iria aparecer o A com o tio "ã")

e queria formatar ela para que saia assim:
QString str = "Macarrão integral.\nMacarrão integral.\n"

não sei a formatação/charset dessa string, porém queria poder pegar e transformar todos os caracteres especiais dela o "ã" da primeira palavra macarrão " & # x e 3 ; "  e deixar corretamente e se possível trocar também todas as tags html (no caso esse < br/>) por um \n, por exemplo...

como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 2):

Não há um método específico na Qt para decodificar entities, mas um contorno é usar

```
QTextDocument *texto= new QTextDocument();
texto->setHtml( "Macarr&#xe3;o integral<br>" );
```

e pegar "convertido" com

```
texto->getPlainText();
```

Comment: usei a função toPlainText(); porém fiquei com o caracter em hexa e em outras partes da string que (não a do exemplo acima) tinham caracteres "ã, ú e etc.." foram alterados... mas obrigado mesmo assim, já me deu uma direção pra pesquisar.

Comment: @Evandro Verifique se você está trabalhando com a Qt no mesmo encoding do seu texto, senão o resultado é imprevisível.